# Dynamic dns entry discovery

Tags: security, networking, dns

How are dynamic dns entries discovered by hackers and what tools are they using to glean this information?

A few days ago I signed up at no-ip.org for a free dns entry in order to open up my e-commerce site to a third party that needs to make calls to it in my development environment. Within a day I saw ip addresses coming to my site that are NOT from this third party. I’m wondering how this brand new dns entry was discovered and so quickly. At least one of these persons was attempting to hack the site and knew exactly the base product I was working with, an open source e-commerce system, and attempted to gain access to the admin area which has got me curious on how exactly these hackers are able to pull this information so quickly and know exactly the product I’m working with.

For now I’ve white-listed the ip addresses from this third party but I’d like to use the same logic these hackers are to look at my site from a security standpoint and better protect against it when we go to production.

Comment: Offtopic, but you should realize that scanners will target ranges of IPs, and bypass DNS entirely if need be. If something's on a public IP, it **WILL* get scanned at some point, even if there's no dns mapping for it. After all, there's only ~2^24 useable IPs. Doesn't take particularly long to scan chunks of that.

Answer (score 0):

To be alerted to new IPs listed in a nameserver requires privileged access to the zone files on the server, regardless of whether those IPs are entered through manual edits to the zone files or through an automated process like DDNS. A quick check shows that those rights aren't enabled by default through the standard mechanism at no-ip.

```
> server nf5.no-ip.com
Default Server:  nf5.no-ip.com
Address:  83.222.240.75

> ls no-ip.com
[nf5.no-ip.com]
*** Can't list domain no-ip.com: Server failed
The DNS server refused to transfer the zone no-ip.com to your computer. If this
is incorrect, check the zone transfer security settings for no-ip.com on the DNS
server at IP address 83.222.240.75.
```

They do [enable zone-transfers by-request](http://support.no-ip.com/customer/portal/articles/352328-how-do-i-allow-zone-transfers-to-another-dns-server-), and I suppose that would be a nice thing for a hacker monitor. Fresh servers have the easiest vulnerabilities.

But honestly, it's just as likely that it was a random IP hit, as Marc suggested. To get your product info also isn't hard. After cataloging the server as a new device, it's typically easy to identify the service platform. Just establishing a TCP/IP connection to the server will typically reveal the operating system it runs through subtle tells in number sequences in IP packets and other tidbits of information. It can look deceptively like someone knew all about your server upon first connection.